# Cannot retrieve theme options on index.php

Tags: theme-options

I have a theme for which I am able to retrieve The theme options on the header.php file by declaring a global variable and save the options in a variable.

```
<?php
global $options_name;
$options = get_option($options_name);
//$options returns the theme options when called on header.php but an empty array on index.php

?>
```

I am returned an empty array when I declare the same global variable and store the options in a variable in index.php of the theme files.

How can I retrieve the theme options in index.php file, as it works fine in header.php?

here is the header.php file:

```
<?php global $option_name; 
$options = get_option($option_name);
?>
<!DOCTYPE PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'PuraVida' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>                
       <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-dropdown.js"></script>


   <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
        <header class="wrap">
            <div class="logoarea">
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $options["logo"]; ?>" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navmenu">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => FALSE ) ) ?>
            </div>

        </header>
```

And Here is the index.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us both header.php and index.php where you are retrieving theme option?

Comment: @VinodDalvi It is a normal header.php and index.php file that a theme has, but the weird thing is that theme options are being retrieved in header.php file but it isnt working for index.php file, I have tried re-declaring the global variable $options_name in index.php but no luck

Comment: @Marh that's why i am asking you to show me code so that i can troubleshoot it.

Comment: @VinodDalvi Alright I have updated the question with codes that  I have in header.php and index.php

Comment: How are you accessing it in index.php file? Have you tried doing global $options_name; echo $options_name; in index.php file? What's your $options_name? Are you replacing it with your real $options_name?

Comment: Yes I have tried globalizing the $options_name in index.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10478/discussion-between-vinod-dalvi-and-mark)

Comment: @VinodDalvi sorry buddy it doesn't allow me to answer my own question currently,so here is the answer: **I passed in the $options_name by value instead of by reference and it worked in index.php too.

Here is how:

    `<?php
    // I was globalizing $global_name, it was equal to value "my_theme_options", so I passed it as a value instead of reference and it worked.
    $options = get_option('my_theme_options');
    ?>`

PS: Thanks to VinodDalvi for all the help.**

Comment: @VinodDalvi It doesn't allow me to answer my own question currently

Comment: ok then i have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing 'my_theme_options' directly to get_option() function instead of storing it in variable as following.

```
$options = get_option('my_theme_options');
```

Instead of

```
global $option_name; 
$options = get_option($option_name);
```